# Quantum Theory just lazy physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations, probability

Is it true that physicists decided that because they couldn't predict with certainty the location of an electron at any given time, that they just created equations using probability instead, still allowing them the ability to invent new technology and other things without actually stripping away every single factor known or unknown and really finding out why there is a quantum leap?

Comment: @JG Questions: scientists worked hard for 25 years to come up with quantum mechanics; and they have been working hard ever since to use it to exploit the properties of nature that were previously hidden. Much of modern technology comes from that and related research and development.  If you have a specific question,  ask it plain and simple.

Comment: So....you're asking if, for example, Paul Dirac, was driven by intellectual laziness?   Did you ask this before or after reading his textbook and/or papers?

Comment: guys: just a detail, but "laziness" is not necessarily pejorative. like "weak forms".

Answer (score 9):

You have it backwards. Classical physics in which objects have certainty of location is the lazy physics. Quantum Mechanics is the real world.

Comment: in a relative sense Dirk is right and i doubt he is approaching this problem saying that there will never be a truer description of the physical world. Its just currently the strongest descriptor of the real world

Answer (score 7):

> without actually stripping away every single factor known or unknown and really finding out why there is a quantum leap?

Physicists have been working hard examining the fundamentals of quantum mechanics, while technology has run away with its applications.

1) They have not found experimentally contradictions with the quantum mechanical models. The experiments are in the thousands if not millions.

2) Theorists have examined under which conditions there might be an underlying level from which quantum mechanical axioms emerge  ,  similar to the emergence of classical axioms from the  quantum mechanical level. There is the famous [Bell inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem)

> In its simplest form, Bell's theorem states:
>
> No physical theory of local hidden variables can ever reproduce all of the predictions of quantum mechanics.

[Experiments performed](http://drchinese.com/David/Bell_Theorem_Easy_Math.htm) validate Bell's theorem, the measured values fit the quatnum mechanical predictions and not underlying local classical deterministic levels.

3) Despite this there exists  theorists who still are searching for a deterministic under layer from which quantum mechanics might  emerge, a Nobel laureate,  G. 't Hooft is one of them and has contributed to this site. Read the [answers he has given](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) for deterministic systems.

You must really not know enough physics to call quantum physics lazy physics. It is intellectually much more challenging and needs more elbow grease than classical physics. Most detractors of quantum mechanics come up with really simplistic models for an underlying deterministic level, and have not mastered all the data from experiments that have to be correctly slotted in any new theory.

Comment: Bell inequalities are violated by QM. I.e. experiments have found that it doesn't hold

Comment: @innisfree I was lazy and hand waved wrongly. I am correcting

Answer (score 3):

You suspect that QM is lazy physics, as rather than calculating exact equations for the position and momentum of e.g. an electron, we describe the electron with uncertainty. Perhaps, if we worked tirelessly, we could account for microscopic factors and degrees of freedom and calculate things exactly?

Not so, alas. The source of probability in QM is not our ignorance or averaging of microscopic details of particles. QM is inherently probabilistic.

There are, in fact, differences between probabilities in QM (based on a 2-norm) and classical probabilities that describe uncertainty (based on a 1-norm). A consequence of this is that so-called Bell-inequalities are violated by QM. This violation is observed: we find observations that would be impossible if the apparent randomness in nature were a result of our ignorance about hidden factors or variables.

In conclusion, QM is not lazy physics, as the probabilities are inherent and not a result of e.g. our own uncertainty about the precise details of a system.

Comment: There are caveats with non-locality etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. There is a common misconception with the "[uncertainity principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)", which name is really misleading, and is indeed the "indetermination principle": the precise information of location really not exist. 
Also it is proven (via some assumptions) that there are not [hidden variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_variable_theory) explaining the "randomness", or some experiments would give different results.

Answer (score 2):

No. Experiment has already been done.

in a Young two-slits experiment (actually, historically, what really done is spin, but the physics is same) Question: which slit the electron goes through? Classically, either slit, right?

*The experiment has been done, and the result is:*

1.) NOT the right slit

2.) NOT the left slit.

3.) NOT both slits.

4.) NOT NEITHER slits.

It is superposition. Classical physics (specifically to this question, the idea of a point mass itself and it *always* gets a location) is doomed to be wrong.